# How do I fix the conditions within my function?

Tags: c

When I run my code, the output only prints the `else` statement. How can I fix that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printIt();
int num;

int main(){
    int num;
    printf("What is your annual income? ", &num);
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printIt();
}

void printIt() {                                      // If user makes over 90,000, machine will print congratulations.
                                                       // If user makes less than 90,000 machine will print keep going.
    if(num > 90000){
        printf("Congratulations, you are doing great!");
        return;
    }
    else{
        printf(" You will make $90,000, if you keep going.");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain the `&num` on the end of the `printf` line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two variables both called `num`. One is created in `main` and is local to `main`. The other is global. Look for `int num;` in your code and you'll see that there are two of them.

I would suggest you get rid of the global `num` and instead pass `num` to `printIt`. The easier (but worse) solution is to get rid of the local `num` in `main`.

Comment: Don’t promote a bad solution. Just promote the good solution. 

Comment: I am stuck on passing the `num` variable to my function `printIt`

Comment: @Zachary.Oliver1 Look at any C documentation or example that covers passing a parameter to a function.